# Getting 403 status code in retrofit2 in POST request

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to post JSON data in the server using retrofit2 but I am getting 403 status code,  [see my postman window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Dvj.png),

i tried passing all headers that is added by postman but still it gives 403 status code, and it is running  successfully in postman but not running in android retrofit

Hear

my retrofit codes are :-

```
public interface ApiInterface {


String BASE_URL = "https:example.com";

 @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json",
        "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2",
        "Accept: */*",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Postman-Token: 9151e8a4-7665 - 416d - b2f5 - a84f0736a7ba",
        "Host: xyz.com",
        "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br",
        "Content-Length: 76" })


@POST("add_aadharinfo")
Call<DataClass> posImages(@Body JSONObject data);
}
```

My MainActivity retrofit codes:-

```
 private void ImageInfo() throws JSONException {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ApiInterface.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

   




    JSONObject dataInfo = new JSONObject();
    dataInfo.put("phone",contact);
    dataInfo.put("profile_image",encoded);
    dataInfo.put("aadhar_image",encoded22);
    Call<DataClass> usercall = apiInterface.posImages(dataInfo);

   

   usercall.enqueue(new Callback<DataClass>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<DataClass> call, retrofit2.Response<DataClass> response) {
           if (response.isSuccessful())
           {
               Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,response.body().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           }
           Log.d("response", "onResponse: "+response.code());
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<DataClass> call, Throwable t) {
           Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,"fail"+t.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   });

}
```

My dataClass:-

```
public class DataClass {
private String message;
private String data;


public DataClass(String message, String data) {
    this.message = message;
    this.data = data;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of Postman authentication tab?